# Google Sheets Client undefined with Node

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble grabbing the sheets object in node. I am able to authenticate, but when I try to read the given sheet, `client.sheets` returns undefined. Which is weird because the sheets object is populated with data as shown below. Even if I pass in the the client like `readSheets(gapi.client)`and log the variable inside readSheets it still returns undefined. Why is this happening?

```
    var CLIENT_ID = 'MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var API_KEY = 'MYAPIKEY';
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets";

    gapi.load('client', {
        callback: function() {
          initClient();
        },
        onerror: function() {
          alert('gapi.client failed to load!');
        }
      });

    const initClient = () => {
        console.log(gapi.client)
        gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            scope: SCOPES
        });
        readSheets();
    }

    function readSheets() {
        console.log(gapi.client.sheets); // undefined
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId: 'MySpreadsheetID',
            majorDimension: "COLUMNS",
            range: 'Sheet1!A1:B2',
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.result.values)
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        }); 
    }
```

`gapi.client` then `gapi.client.sheets` in the console:

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry. Can I ask you about the method for running your script? Because I thought that your script might be Javascript.

Comment: @Tanaike you are correct js

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your run your script at your browser. I understand like this. In this case, where is Node.js used?

Comment: @tanaike localhost?

Comment: I thought that when gaip is used, it is required to load ``https://apis.google.com/js/api.js`` or ``https://apis.google.com/js/client.js``. You can see the sample script at [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples). But because I'm not sure about your environment of Node.js, I had asked about it.

Comment: Its so weird. In the browser it works perfectly but as soon as I introduce node it breaks. Same code

Comment: Try to infer your NodeJS implementation from this [NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs). You should get your nodejs code running in no time. After that, check the [Sheets API Samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) for basic API calls and the [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Browser aka Client-Side aka GAPI on the backend (in NodeJS environment).

For NodeJS you should use [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) library - [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis).

For Browser you should use GAPI (https://apis.google.com/js/api.js). If you want to use TypeScript with GAPI - you should install [@types/gapi.client.sheets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gapi.client.sheets) or generate typing yourself using [google-api-typings-generator](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/google-api-typings-generator).

For more details about the difference between these two use-cases, refer to: [JavaScript VS NodeJS Google API Clients](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/google-api-typings-generator#javascript-vs-nodejs-clients)